# How to Display Office 365 Room Calendar View in SharePoint

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph, exchange-online

Is it possible to display office room calendar in SharePoint- Modern UI site.
Is there anything out of the box, and if its supposed to be a custom development
What api should we be looking at?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a web part for viewing Microsoft 365 group calendars but I don't believe this works for room calendars.

You could build your own web part to display the room calendar information via the [Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/outlook-calendar-concept-overview).

Comment: Thanks Callum it seems thats the only way

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer helped you, please up vote it or mark as the accepted answer to help inform the community.